# MySQL max() - not returning max() value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, max

I have a query which I want to return the highest id value in `idevent` that is within a given range of sensor ID's (`sensorID`) however the query is not returning the highest value.

The results when I run the query minus the `max()` statment:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM events WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "2015-03-09 10:45:35" - INTERVAL 4000 SECOND AND "2015-03-09 10:45:35" AND (sensorID = 34035434 OR sensorID = 34035492 OR sensorID = 34035426 OR sensorID = 34035482 OR sensorID = 34035125 OR sensorID = 34035498 OR sensorID = 34035508 OR sensorID = 34035444 OR sensorID = 34035418 OR sensorID = 34035466 OR sensorID = 34035128 OR sensorID = 34035119 OR sensorID = 34035448 OR sensorID = 34037294 OR sensorID = 34035549);
+---------+---------------------+----------+-------+
| idevent | timestamp           | sensorID | event |
+---------+---------------------+----------+-------+
|  117794 | 2015-03-09 10:14:58 | 34035434 |     9 |
|  117795 | 2015-03-09 10:15:03 | 34035508 |     9 |
|  117796 | 2015-03-09 10:15:17 | 34035508 |     1 |
+---------+---------------------+----------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The results given when the `max()` statement is added as a `HAVING` clause:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM events WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "2015-03-09 10:45:35" - INTERVAL 4000 SECOND AND "2015-03-09 10:45:35" AND (sensorID = 34035434 OR sensorID = 34035492 OR sensorID = 34035426 OR sensorID = 34035482 OR sensorID = 34035125 OR sensorID = 34035498 OR sensorID = 34035508 OR sensorID = 34035444 OR sensorID = 34035418 OR sensorID = 34035466 OR sensorID = 34035128 OR sensorID = 34035119 OR sensorID = 34035448 OR sensorID = 34037294 OR sensorID = 34035549) HAVING max(idevent);
+---------+---------------------+----------+-------+
| idevent | timestamp           | sensorID | event |
+---------+---------------------+----------+-------+
|  117794 | 2015-03-09 10:14:58 | 34035434 |     9 |
+---------+---------------------+----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why is this not returning the lastest value?

Comment: You basically filter by `HAVING TRUE`, don't you?

Comment: You mean I want my having statement to be true for the value I want to return?

Comment: why not add this at the end `order by idevent desc limit 1`

Comment: You are using the `HAVING` clause in a wrong way.

Comment: Fair enough, Abhik solution worked as I needed so if he would like to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with `order by limit`, so all you need to add the following at the end of the given first query

```
order by idevent desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use as , use [order by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "2015-03-09 10:45:35" - INTERVAL 4000 SECOND AND "2015-03-09 10:45:35" AND (sensorID = 34035434 OR sensorID = 34035492 OR sensorID = 34035426 OR sensorID = 34035482 OR sensorID = 34035125 OR sensorID = 34035498 OR sensorID = 34035508 OR sensorID = 34035444 OR sensorID = 34035418 OR sensorID = 34035466 OR sensorID = 34035128 OR sensorID = 34035119 OR sensorID = 34035448 OR sensorID = 34037294 OR sensorID = 34035549)
 order by idevent desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this query:

```
SELECT MAX(idevent) FROM events WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "2015-03-09 10:45:35" - INTERVAL 4000 SECOND AND "2015-03-09 10:45:35" AND sensorID IN ('34035434', '34035492', '34035426', '34035482', '34035125', '34035498', '34035508', '34035444', '34035418', '34035466', '34035128', '34035119', '34035448', '34037294', '34035549') GROUP BY idevent;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `OR` part of your answer?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have not used the `IN` function before

Answer (score 0):

go here   http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp

the query is wrong.

try this:

```
SELECT MAX(Price) FROM events WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "2015-03-09 10:45:35" - INTERVAL 4000 SECOND AND "2015-03-09 10:45:35" AND (sensorID = 34035434 OR sensorID = 34035492 OR sensorID = 34035426 OR sensorID = 34035482 OR sensorID = 34035125 OR sensorID = 34035498 OR sensorID = 34035508 OR sensorID = 34035444 OR sensorID = 34035418 OR sensorID = 34035466 OR sensorID = 34035128 OR sensorID = 34035119 OR sensorID = 34035448 OR sensorID = 34037294 OR sensorID = 34035549);
```